# Linking a special shared library

Tags: c, linker

I need to link a shared library (LuaSocket) I'm compiling against another special shared library, `liblua5.1`, that isn't in one of the normal locations.  To do this I'm modifying the Makefile.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, but this particular step that I modified fails:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/media/sda2/crank/lib gcc -O -shared -fpic -l liblua5.1 -o socket.so.2.0.2 [...]
```

(where `[...]` is a list of `.o` files that just got built).  When I build, I get the error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/../../../../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lliblua5.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [socket.so.2.0.2] Error 1
```

Inspection of the `LIBRARY_PATH` confirms that the needed library is there:

```
# ls /media/sda2/crank/lib/
lgre.so  libgre.so  libgreio.a  liblua.so  liblua5.1.so  libsbexternal.so
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `-l liblua5.1` to `-llua5.1`.

Also, instead of setting `LIBRARY_PATH`, why not use the `-L` option? Example: `-L/media/sda2/crank/lib`.

Comment: Glorious, thank you.  I will never fully understand the intricacies of dynamic linking.

Comment: "lib" is automatically added to the start of the library name.